# css PIE just not working

Tags: css

I am trying to show rounded corners with CSS PIE, and it is just not working.  Please take a look at [my website for reference](http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz).  You will see that in IE7 & IE8 there are no rounded corners on the little log in area up top, nor the nav buttons in the header (and several other places).

Here is a snippet of CSS code:

```
hgroup > div {
padding-bottom:5px;
background:#003399;
border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
behavior:url(http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/app/webroot/js/PIE.htc);
position:relative;
text-align:center;
color:#FF9900;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,102,0.7);
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,102,0.7);
 box-shadow:1px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,102,0.7);

}
```

I can access the url by typing it into a browser, so I know that works.  I have tried uploading the PIE.php file into this folder and using that instead, as well as the .js file.  So even if there was a content-type problem, serving the php file should have solved that.  I have position:relative to force hasLayout.
 Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with the PIE behavior not being applied, check your server configuration and if possible update it to use the correct content-type. For Apache, you can do this in a .htaccess file:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

For IE8 you need to add additionally

```
-ms-behavior:url(http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/app/webroot/js/PIE.htc);
```

it needs the -ms- at the beginning

Comment: I have added this to all of my .htaccess files (I am using Cakephp), I even have used behavior:  url(http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/app/webroot/js/PIE.php); just to make sure that wasn't the problem.  And I tried using -ms- in front, at least to see if I could get IE8 to work.  It does not.